# bash in python : sed unterminated s command

Tags: python, bash

Below command runs fine in bash.

```
/folk/vlm/commandline/./vlmTool find -l all | grep -e "^Target ID" -e "City" -e "Zone" | sed "s#.*City.*#&\n#g" > new.txt
```

But in python when I try to execute the same command I get:

```
['sed', 's#.*City.*#&\n#g']
**sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command**
```

code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python -tt

import subprocess
import shlex
cmd = '/folk/vlm/commandline/./vlmTool find -l all | grep -e "^Target ID" -e "City" -e "Zone" | sed "s#.*City.*#&\n#g" > new.txt'
cmd2= "/folk/vlm/commandline/./vlmTool find -l all"
args1 = shlex.split(cmd2)
cmd3 = 'grep -e "^Target ID" -e "City" -e "Zone"'
args2 = shlex.split(cmd3)
cmd4 =  'sed "s#.*City.*#&\n#g"'
args3 = shlex.split(cmd4)
print args3
p1 = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(args2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(args3, stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.stdout.close()
output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Try `['sed', r's#.*City.*#&\n#g']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `\n` sequence is understood in python as an escape sequence for a newline; so sed is thinking you're done with the `s` command and starting a new one.  to get the backslash included in the string, either escape it, as in `...\\n...` or use a raw string: `r's#.*City.*#&\n#g'`

Comment: thanks...\\n worked with the desired output but using r doesn't provide me with the desired result.

Comment: you're the best.

Comment: Thanks. Saved my time. Had been googling for a while.